# Integration Test: How to reduce running time of tests in Java?

Tags: java, spring, maven, testing, integration-testing

We have suffered from long running time for our integration tests in a Java (Spring Boot) project. I have a look at several pages to fix the problem, but I have not found a proper solution for that. There is some silent running option as [Run Java Tests With Maven Silently (Only Log on Failure)](https://rieckpil.de/run-java-tests-with-maven-silently-only-log-on-failure/), but I think it is used for brevity on the console.

So, is there any approach to reduce the running time for integration tests in Java?

Here is an example integration test to give a rough idea:

```
class MenuServiceImplTest extends MenuBaseTests {

    // code omitted for breavity
    

    @Autowired
    private MenuService menuService;

    @Autowired
    private BrandBaseTests brandBaseTests;


    @BeforeEach
    void prep() throws Exception {
        menuDTO = createMenu(menuName, brandDTO.getUuid());
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    @Rollback
    void test_Demo() {
        assertNotNull(menuDTO.getUuid());
        assertEquals(menuName, menuDTO.getName());
        assertEquals("Description", menuDTO.getDescription());
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Are you using @SpringBootApplication annotation for integration test ?

Comment: @Turac I added an example, but I am afraid there is no `@SpringBootApplication` except from `public class Application {}` part in our project. Should we use it for integration test as well? How?

Comment: Integration tests are well known for taking time. That is why unit tests are so useful so that you can have fewer integration tests that focus on the most important parts of your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot amigo. But maybe there is something that I could check or change in order to make is faster. Any idea?

Comment: And any idea about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70714648/unit-test-how-to-capture-saved-value-in-java ?

Comment: Well known approach to reduce execution time is to run tests in parallel. Junit 5 makes this possible with annotation `@Execution(ExecutionMode.CONCURRENT)`. But you need to make sure your tests are independent. You might need `@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.MethodMode.BEFORE_METHOD)`