# How to capture saved value in Java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to create a unit test for the following method:

```
public CommandDTO update(final MenuRequest request) {
    Menu menu = menuRepository.findByUuid(request.getUuid());

    MenuConverter.convert(request, menu); // map fields
    Menu saved = menuRepository.save(menu);
    return CommandDTO.builder().uuid(saved.getUuid()).build();
}
```

I want to capture `saved` parameter as it is not returned from the method using the following unit test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MenuServiceImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private MenuServiceImpl menuService;

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<Menu> menuCaptor;

    // mocks (code omitted for brevity)

    @Test
    public void test_Update() {

        // ...

        CommandDTO result = menuService.update(request);

        verify(menuRepository).save(menuCaptor.capture());
        final Menu captured = menuCaptor.getValue();
    }
}
```

However, the parameter in `menuRepository.save()` is the unsaved parameter, but I need to capture `saved` parameter. So, how can I do this? Should I use `@Spy` instead of `ArgumentCaptor`?

Comment: If you are mocking the `MenuRepository` then you are in control of what the `save` method should return, you can specify the return i.e. `saved` parameter your self using the `when-then` statements

Comment: What do you mean, could you post the example code? on the other hand, if I follow that approach, I would give the saved object's value, but in this scene how can I test it?

Comment: Usually, when you write a unit test, you mock all the dependencies. For instance, for `MenuServiceImpl` for which we are writing test, `MenuRepository` should be mocked, then only we will be able to test the functioning of `MenuServiceImpl` in isolation. Also, you don't need to test if `MenuRepository` is working correctly in the test of `MenuServiceImpl`, for that you can write another test for `MenuRepository` to test its working. If at all you have to test through layers and use a combination of mocks and actual class invocation, you can use @Spy annotation.

Comment: I already mock all the necessary repo and services that I used to test methods. However, I what you mean is a little bit confused. Could you simply post an example test for this `update` method just by modifying my test in the question?

Comment: I set the updated fields in `request` parameter and need to check if the saved parameter's field is updated or not. So, I need a different thing rather than mocking I think. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If that is a unit test, then I assume you already mock `MenuRepository`.

To properly mock `MenuRepository`, you need to define the behavior of `menuRepository.findByUuid(request.getUuid())` and `menuRepository.save(menu)`.

Once you define `menuRepository.findByUuid(request.getUuid())`, you need to create a `Menu` instance. All you need to do is, to check if the fields of that `menu` are updated properly.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to break down the functionality of the `MenuServiceImpl`'s `update` method:

```
public CommandDTO update(final MenuRequest request) {
    Menu menu = menuRepository.findByUuid(request.getUuid());

    MenuConverter.convert(request, menu); // map fields
    Menu saved = menuRepository.save(menu);
    return CommandDTO.builder()
        .uuid(saved.getUuid())
        .build();
}
```

Here is what this method is doing:

1. Fetching existing `Menu` from the repository, finding by `uuid`
2. Converting it i.e. updating it from `request`
3. Persisting it back in repository using `save`
4. Creating a `CommandDTO` from saved uuid.

Now, when we write *UnitTest* for a unit then that means we are testing the working of that unit only.
Here `MenuServiceImpl` is not responsible to ensure whether the values were mapped correctly or if the updated value was saved correctly, the only work `MenuServiceImpl` performs is to call these dependencies in a particular order and that is all we need to test here.
So, here is a correct test for `MenuServiceImpl`'s `update` method:

```
@Test
void test_Update() {

    MenuRequest request = new MenuRequest("1234");

    Menu existingMockMenu = mock(Menu.class);
    when(menuRepository.findByUuid("1234")).thenReturn(existingMockMenu);

    Menu savedMockMenu = mock(Menu.class);
    when(menuRepository.save(existingMockMenu)).thenReturn(savedMockMenu);

    menuServiceImpl.update(request);

    verify(menuRepository).save(existingMockMenu);
}
```

If at all you want to test if `MenuRepository` is saving the `Menu` correctly, you will have to write a new test for `MenuRepository`, if this is actually a repository that interacts with the database, then it will be helpful to write DB Integration Test.

Regarding using `ArgumentCaptor`, let's suppose your `MenuConverter` is changing the values of the `menu`, something like this:

```
public class MenuConverter {

    public static void convert(MenuRequest request, Menu menu) {
        menu.setName(request.getName() + "_new");
    }

}
```

then first of all, you should have a different test for `MenuConverter` that tests this logic, still if you want to test this in the test of `MenuServiceImpl` itself, then you don't have to use `ArgumentCaptor`, you can use something like:

```
@Test
void test_Update() {

// same as above

  verify(existingMockMenu).setName("Menu1_new");
}
```

This verifies that `MenuConverter` attempted to update the name of your `existingMockMenu`